# Is it possible to leverage ie9's rendering engine in .NET programmatically?

Tags: c#-4.0, internet-explorer-9

I'm looking for a programmatic way to capture web output using IE9's improved rendering engine. Is this possible from .NET code? (I'm *not* looking to use the WebBrowser control in a winform/wpf context.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wait so what exactly do you want to do? Render a webpage outside of IE using IE9 engine?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. I want to capture the output of a webpage using ie9's engine, programatically.

Comment: The problem with that I believe is that the rendering engine is used in ShDocVw which is used in both IE and the windows file explorer so I'm not sure if you can redirect output but you can see if the COM interface for ShDocVw.dll has something you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I haven't found any ready-made wrappers for leveraging the ie9 engine programmatically.